# How do I get the length of the secondary field in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to print the length of the second 10 in field 2d array, but I didn't know how. I want to create another for loop inside of this one and have it count to its length.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[][] field = new Object[10][10];

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Length: " + i);
        }

        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }

}
```

Comment: System.out.println("Length: " + field[i].length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its kind of two-dimensional array and you can get the length of second array like this `field[i].length` and use it in your nested loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[][] field = new Object[10][10];

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Total Rows: " + field.length);
            for(int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++){
               System.out.println("Row: " + i);
               System.out.println("Length: " + field[i].length);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`field` is a matrix, which is an array of arrays.
That means that `field[i]` is an array. Specifically, an array of `Object`. If you want that array's length, you just call `.length`

So the answer is `System.out.println("Length: " + field[i].length);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could approach this using a nested for loop, as you requested.
The solution would look something like this.

```
for( int r = 0; r<field.length; r++ ) {
    System.out.println("Length: " + r);
    for( int c = 0; c<field[0].length; c++) {
        System.out.println("Length: " + c);
    }
}
```

The console messages may not be what you wanted but the header for how long the loop runs would be `c<field[0].length;`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`field` is an array containing other arrays of 10 length each. Doing `field[i]` will get the array at index `i` from `field`. Therefore using `field[i].length` will get the length of the array at index `i`. tho count the lengths of all the arrays inside `field` you would use:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object[][] field = new Object[10][10];

        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Length: " + field[i].length);
        }

        System.out.println("Goodbye.");
    }

}
```